# Not able to connect to sql server 2008 from java working fine on my system not not working on server system

Tags: java, sql-server-2008

I want to pull up data from a remote server (Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0) from java, i have few permission on the server. i have permission to access a view  of a database from that server. there no problem when i am using sql express, and also  its working fine on my system( i am able to pull the data from the specified server from my system ) , but its not working on the application system ..

here is connection string i am using

```
url="jdbc:sqlserver://<ipaddress>:1433;
Instance=;databaseName=CentralDB";
driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
Class.forName(driver); 
url = url + ";user=" + username + ";password="+ password ";"; 
Class.forName(driver);
Connection con1 = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

here is stacktrace for the error

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot open database "CentralDB" requested by the login. The login failed.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:197)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:246)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:83)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2529)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:1905)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:1893)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4575)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1400)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1045)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:817)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:700)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:842)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:243)
    at com.noufal.db.ConnectDB.<init>(ConnectDB.java:27)
    at com.noufal.db.GetEmps.getEmps(GetEmps.java:48)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:78)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1813)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
SQLState(S0001) vendor code(4060)
```

please help to solve this issue...

Comment: Posting a stack trace is all well and good but, we also need to see _how_ you are attempting to connect to the database in order to help you effectively.

Comment: Which connection string are you using?

Comment: thanks for your replys....this is my code , i am changing my question also with the code...url=jdbc:sqlserver://<ipaddress>:1433;Instance=;databaseName=CentralDB
username=<username>
password=<passowrd>
driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriverClass.forName(driver);
String url = url + ";user=" + username + ";password="+ password ";";
Class.forName(driver);Connection con1 = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

Answer (score 0):

its username password issue

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot open database "CentralDB" requested by the login. The login failed.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing your `url` string variable, perhaps something to do with formation of the connection string. If you cant see anything wrong, try connecting with that url generated. Also check if the application system can access that IP Address

Comment: The problem I faced because i used different way of starting the server, one with "startup.bat " another from services , i used a property file to get the connection string i was reading it System.getproperty() method so the these different type starting server giving different result and hence the property file was not reading.... thanks for supports...